# How can I select a single property from PowerShell Expandproperty

Tags: powershell, select-object

I have a simple PowerShell expression that returns some object properties. It also returns an object called Computer which has a property called `ComputerName` which I'm trying to access. The `ExpandProperty` switch returns all the properties. How do I filter it to return the properties I need?

Here's the expression:

```
foreach ($computer in $jobinstancestatus.Computers) {
    Select-Object -InputObject $computer -property Status,ResultsPath -ExpandProperty Computer
}
```

I tried this but it gave an error when I tried to run it.

```
foreach ($computer in $jobinstancestatus.Computers) {
    Select-Object -InputObject $computer -property Status,ResultsPath (-ExpandProperty Computer).ComputerName
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (inside the loop):

```
Select-Object -InputObject $computer -property Status,ResultsPath,@{N='Computer_ComputerName';E={$_.Computer.ComputerName}}
```

It's using a "calculated property" to get the value you need.

Comment: Heh....thinking about creating PSObjects.  Editing to fix.  Thanks @AnsgarWiechers.